# How to reduce the apk size of Android app which need openCv lib( only for Image processing)

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, java-native-interface, native

I'm building an Android app with min SDK `15`, which uses OpenCV library.The problem is when I build apk size of it is more than `60` MB which is not very great.

I checked the app file, I could see that the size is too big due to `libopencv_java3.so` file in all architectures like `amr64`, `armeabi`, `mips`, `x86` etc.

[image]

I am using opneCv only for image processing.This library has a lot of other features like video processing, 3d image, object detection and much more, which I don't need in my app like

If I remove all those files and build APK, then size will be reduced 50 MB, but to make this app work I need to install `OpenCVManager` to run my app.

Is there any way by which I can reduce my apk size?

Or is it possible just to extract only the feature from `OpenCV` which I am interested in and create `.so` for those features?

Comment: Is this library contains more resource size??

Comment: @ArpitPatel this is wrapper of library written in c++ . So integrate in our app we need to include .so file in our jnilib folder

Comment: Are you aware about progardrule ?? It might help to remove unnecessary code but its not work every time. But still you can try and before you use make it backup of your project for your safer side.

Comment: On Using progard with OpneCv. OpenCV becomes inaccessible

Comment: In that case you need to contact on OpenCV developer so they can help.

Comment: See my updated answer I added a question answer site for OpenCV so you can ask question there. It might help.

Comment: You need to download OpenCV library project and then you can modified that library.

Comment: You can make multiple APKs for the different architectures.  That way each apk only has 1 copy of the .so.  Google Play supports this, and will download the appropriate version.  Although realistically-  pretty much everything is ARM, all non-ARM devices combines make up a tiny portion of the market.

Comment: If you are willing to invest enough time in shrinking the apk size, you could try to move all image processing functions into native c++ code, which will ensure that only the absolute necessary functions will remain in the apk. A quick test indicated that when performing a simple Canny edge detector, the total size of the library would come down to 1.9Mb.

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz i need some help regards opencv image processing? Can I touch with you?

Comment: @AbdulMuheet sure

Comment: Can you send me your email or fb ID, the given fb id is not working! muheetks@gmail.com

Comment: @AbdulMuheet is you issue resolved ? i am also stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @AbdulMuheet yes my problem resolved . Please have a look on accepted answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me, [alijandro answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44965185/1842414) 2nd answer was the best solution but I got stuck in the process. So, I solved the issue by apk split. You need to upload apk's related to the platform and also a universal apk.It would be ideal , since OpenCV doesn't provide adding dependency at module level.

Universal apk will be downloaded in case platform does not match.[**Here**](https://blog.mindorks.com/publishing-multiple-apks-on-google-play-b06bb9078aae) is nicely written blog about apk publishing mutiple apk. You need to maintain same app id , Keystore, same app version but different code version

**Step 1**.Add gradle code for spk split. Include the architecture for which you want to create separate apk.

```
android{
//......
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi","armeabi-v7a",'arm64-v8a',"mips","x86","x86_64",'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
}
```

**Step 2**.Add below code for different Code version for different platform.

```
android{
//......
}
ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 3, 'armeabi-v7a': 4, 'arm64-v8a': 5, 
mips: 6, 'x86': 7, 'x86_64': 8]
import com.android.build.OutputFile
// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination 
// of ABI APK value * 1000 + defaultConfig.versionCode
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
// assign different version code for each output
variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def abiFilter = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
    def abiMultiplier = 0
    if (abiFilter != null) {
        abiMultiplier = project.ext.versionCodes.get(abiFilter)
    }
    output.versionCodeOverride =
            abiMultiplier * 1000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
   }
  }
```

For Example, if the initial version code was 1, then generated codes will be:

```
 armeabi -> 3001
 armeabi-v7a -> 4001
 arm64-v8a -> 5001
 mips -> 6001
 x86 -> 7001
 x86_64 -> 8001
```

All together your Gradle code will look like this.

```
 android{
//......
splits {
abi {
    enable true
    reset()
    include "armeabi","armeabi-v7a",'arm64-
v8a',"mips","x86","x86_64",'arm64-v8a'
    universalApk true
 }
 }

 ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 3, 'armeabi-v7a': 4, 'arm64-v8a': 5, 
mips: 6, 'x86': 7, 'x86_64': 8]
import com.android.build.OutputFile
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.each { output ->
def abiFilter = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
def abiMultiplier = 0
if (abiFilter != null) {
    abiMultiplier = project.ext.versionCodes.get(abiFilter)
}
output.versionCodeOverride =
        abiMultiplier * 1000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
}
}
```

Now you need to publish all the apk on playstore one by one.

**Note**: While publishing make sure you retain all the platform and universal apk.

Comment: what is the significance of doing step 2? Why not stick with one universal version while still having an apk for each platform?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran step 2 will generate all the build(ie build variants like armeabi","armeabi-v7a",'arm64-
v8a',"mips","x86","x86_64",'arm64-v8a) at one short with proper name to identify each build

Answer (score 16):

You can not remove the library `libopencv_java3.so`, it's mandatory.

> Is there any way by which I can reduce my apk size?

Without modify the library `libopencv_java3.so`, you can build multiple apks for different architectures rather than package a flat APK. Only one arch of `libopencv_java3.so` will be packaged into your split APK. For example, you can use the configuration below to build only for `x86`, `armeabi-v7a` and `mips` architectures in your `build.gradle`

```
splits {
    abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"
      universalApk false
    }
  }
```

More information about reduce apk size by splitting, see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html).

> Or is it possible just to extract only the feature from OpenCV which I am interested in and create .so for those features?

Yes, of course. The building process for `opencv` is fully customized. If you have already know how to build opencv for Android, go to **step 2** directly.

#### step 1

1. get the source of [opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)
2. create directory `opencv_build`
3. change to root directory of `opencv` you just cloned
4. invoke the build script `platforms/android/build_sdk.py --ndk_path $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT --sdk_path $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT ../opencv_build .`

#### Note

The build procedure need `android` command to build apk, so the Android SDK tool version must less than `25.3.0`, from `25.3.0`, `android` command has been removed.

#### step 2

Assume the **step 1** above run properly. Here I take `armeabi-v7a` as an example.

1. Go to directory `opencv_build/o4a/lib/armeabi-v7a`
2. You will find many *.a for different opencv module, the library `libopencv_java3.so` also in this directory
3. Create a tiny version share library from the module you need, e.g

   ```
   $ arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -shared -o libopencv_tiny.so --sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -Wl,--whole-archive libopencv_core.a libopencv_imgcodecs.a libopencv_imgproc.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
   $ du -h libopencv_tiny.so 
   5.2M    libopencv_tiny.so
   $ arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded libopencv_tiny.so 
   $ du -h libopencv_tiny.so 
   4.1M    libopencv_tiny.so
   $ du -h libopencv_java3.so 
   9.8M    libopencv_java3.so
   ```

The tiny version which include `core`, `image codecs` and `image proc` has a size `4.1M` after strip, but the full version `libopencv_java3.so` has a size of `9.8M`.

I use `libopencv_tiny.so` as the name just for convenience, you have to use the same name `libopencv_java3.so` in your project. Otherwise `System.loadLibrary` in Java can not find the native library.

For the rest of the architecture you need, e.g `arm64-v8a`, do the same.

Comment: I think 2nd solution is the best which I need. But I am getting below error error. `Could not determine machine name of your toolchain.  Probably your Android
  standalone toolchain is broken.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:127 (project)
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`

And I am stuck at this point.

Comment: I have installed ninja also but no success

Comment: How did you invoke the build script `build_sdk.py`? Make sure you have pass `--ndk_path` and `--sdk_path` correctly.

Comment: Starting I was getting error related to path because I did not expose path but now that error is resolved

Comment: How can I add contrib modules when building opencv sdk? And what is the purpose of OpenCV manager? why need it, providing my App packaged the opencv_xx.so

Comment: Can you add extra module with the build option `--extra_modules_path EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` when invoke the build script? `OpenCV Manager` will provide the missing shared library if you didn't bundle them into your apk.

Comment: @alijandro Regarding the command `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`, is there anything similar that you know about mac. I am trying to build a .so file in mac.

Comment: This is not working. It's giving me an error `fatal error: -shared and -static are incompatible`

Comment: Does this work for Mac OS? `FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_6e918.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o` Anyone tried this in mac?