# How app can be split across multiple packages?

Tags: android, package

[Page about App Standby Buckets in docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby) says:

> If apps are split across multiple packages, those packages might be in
>   different buckets and, thus, have different access levels. You should
>   be sure to test such apps with the packages assigned to various
>   buckets to make sure the app behaves properly.

What does it mean - "if apps are split across multiple packages"? How app can be split across multiple packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is referring to Dynamic feature module which allows you to separate certain features and resources from the base module of your app and include them in your app bundle. This allows users to download and install those modules/components on demand (It still requires you to install base SDK).

For more details, you can refer to the official document for [dynamic feature](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#dynamic_feature_modules)

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean different APKs for different platforms. You can compile your app for different CPU architectures.

Take a look here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45074929/1804084