# How to extract only the feature from OpenCV which I am interested in and create a .so for those features?

Tags: java, android, windows, opencv, optimization

After updating OpenCV to 4.1.0 my apk size increased to over 60MB. The libopencv_java4.so file in libs\x86_64 folder is more than 67MB.

I read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44965185/5770941 and there was a way to extract only some feature from OpenCV like core, imgcodecs, imgproc. but i think the answer just work in linuxOS and there wasn't a way for Windows.

What i should do in windows 10 and android studio to extract only some feature like  core, imgcodecs, imgproc from OpenCV and rebuild openCV and create tiny .so files for using in my android project?

Comment: Hi did you find any solution to this issue, please share it with us