# How to reduce the APK size if I'm using OpenCV library

Tags: android, opencv, apk, android-app-bundle

In my current project, I'm using *OpenCV* as the main library to play with image processing, when I  build a bundle debug to check the size of ABB, I find it very huge (**50MB**).

Following this article of [How to Generate and Extract APK Files from Android App Bundle (AAB)](https://www.geekdashboard.com/extract-apk-files-from-aab/), I get this :

[image]

**My Question**

How can I reduce the APK size if I'm using `OpenCV library`, I know there's a way to do that, for example, removing the unused **.SO** file, some apps on Google Play use the *OpenCV library* and their size does not reach **10MB**.

**Gradle file:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maa.abc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

1. OpenCV library version : **4.1.2**
2. Library used to get OpenCV : `com.github.iamareebjamal:opencv-android:4.1.2`

Comment: AAB file serves only the apk meant for the user's device. So in your case if the user is using an *arm64 device* he/she would get **7mb** as your app size not **50mb**.

Comment: @GiddyNaya thank you for your comment, yeah I know, but if the user has an **x86** device the apk size will be **53MB** right?

Comment: An x86 would be the 14mb category... x86_x64_2 equates to *high end x64* which is 53mb which is quite large but devices like this aren't much in terms of market space.

Comment: @Giddy Naya thank you so much for your explanation

Comment: Also see [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45074929/8043806) if it may help

Comment: As an extra data point, there are barely any device with x86 64-bits today.