# How to include only OpenCV Android library that I need?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to use OpenCV library for my Android app (OpenCV 4.6.0). But the size of my app is really big after I added the library. I want to only include the part of the library that I use, which is `imgproc` and `core` (specifically Sobel edge detection). I have tried to edit the CMakeLists.txt (which is located on libcxx_helper) to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

# dummy target to bring libc++_shared.so into packages
add_library(opencv_jni_shared STATIC dummy.cpp)

set(OpenCV_DIR D:/Project/AndroidStudioProject/SobelProject/sdk/native/jni)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc)
add_executable(opencv_sobel dummy.cpp)
target_link_libraries(opencv_sobel core imgproc ${EXTERNAL_LIBS})
```

I expect there will be a `libopencv_sobel.so` generated from the above CMakeLists.txt, but nothing is generated. So, I load the library with this:

```
init {
    System.loadLibrary('opencv_java4')
}
```

Then I run the app. But the size of my app is still the same. I am unfamiliar with C++ and NDK.

Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I follow exactly the same step from the documentation @Rohit Bhati gave.

This is my `Android.mk`

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include D:\Project\AndroidStudioProject\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
```

and this is my `Application.mk`

```
APP_STL := c++_static # I changed it from gnustl_static because it is not supported anymore
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions

APP_ABI := arm64-v8a

APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```

both located at `{myProject}/app/jni` then I ran the `ndk-build`. After it completes, a `libopencv_java4.so` file is generated inside the `libs/armv64-v8` folder, but the size is still the same.

I look into the documentation but I didn't found how to specify what library I want to include. Also, what is the purpose of this code

`OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off`

because it doesn't reduce the `.so` generated file size

**EDIT 2**

I followed the step from the related link by @Rohit Bhati with a slight different because the steps seems old.

```
/d/Project/AndroidStudioProject/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/staticlibs/arm64-v8a
$ D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang++ -shared -o libopencv_java4.so --sysroot=D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -Wl,--whole-archive libopencv_core.a libopencv_imgproc.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive

$ D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip libopencv_java4.so
```

A new `libopencv_java4.so` file then generated with smaller size. Then, I copy it to `opencv-sdk/native/libs/armv64-v8a` replacing the old file (which is bigger one). But, I get this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN3tbb4task13note_affinityEt" referenced by "/data/app/id.indevelopment.edgepaint-pG-fG4NFi7Mj7szExjH9ww==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so"...
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1071)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
        at id.indevelopment.edgepaint.detector.EdgeDetection.<init>(EdgeDetection.kt:17)
        at id.indevelopment.edgepaint.di.AppModuleKt$detectorModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:16)
        at id.indevelopment.edgepaint.di.AppModuleKt$detectorModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:16)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:54)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:111)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:255)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:242)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:205)
        at id.indevelopment.edgepaint.di.AppModuleKt$viewModelModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:22)
        at id.indevelopment.edgepaint.di.AppModuleKt$viewModelModule$1$1.invoke(AppModule.kt:11)
        at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:54)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
        at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:111)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:255)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:242)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:205)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.factory.DefaultViewModelFactory.create(DefaultViewModelFactory.kt:13)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:83)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
        at id.indevelopment.edgepaint.ui.main.MainActivity.getViewModel(MainActivity.kt:77)
        at id.indevelopment.edgepaint.ui.main.MainActivity.setUpViewModel(MainActivity.kt:152)
        at id.indevelopment.edgepaint.ui.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:112)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I'm able to find a decent solution to my problem, which is to build the OpenCV from sources with only the library that I needed. I will share the solution here in case anyone came across a similar situation.

Python is required for this solution. The step is:

1. Get the OpenCV latest sources (in zip) from the [GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases).
2. Extract the zip file and open the folder (you should be at the root folder). Skip step 3 if you use `imgcodecs`.
3. Now, from the root folder, go to `modules/java/generator/android/java/org/opencv/android` and open `Utils.java` on any text editor. Comment all code that uses `Imgcodecs` class including the import statement. If you don't comment it, you will get an error when running the command at step 5 as it is trying to find an `imgcodecs` module which we don't include.
4. Back to the root folder and open a command prompt.
5. Run `python platforms/android/build_sdk.py {output_path} ./ --ndk_path={your_ndk_path} --sdk_path={your_sdk_path} --modules_list="core,imgproc,java" --no_samples_build --config=ndk-22.config.py`

   On the `modules_list`, `java` is required to generate the java wrapper. There are some other options available which you can look at the `build_sdk.py` code
6. Wait for the process to complete and you will get the sdk at `{output_path}/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk`

Now, the only problem with this solution is it runs 2-3x slower compared to the (all modules) sdk that OpenCV provided [here](https://opencv.org/releases/) (which is the sdk that I use before).

Comment: What did you mean by "it runs 2-3x slower compared to .."? Did you mean build time or execution (opencv operations)?

Comment: The execution (I specifically use the sobel operator).

Comment: Maybe it is missing the optimizations for vector operations - DNEON or something similar.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. That could be true. Thanks for the added info!

Answer (score 0):

Use Static library linking which will only pull in the functionality you actually want to use in your project instead of the whole library.
This link will be helpful [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c)

or else you can checkout the same sample project of static linking on Github. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I have look into the documentation but still have some problems. You can look at the EDIT section of my question.

Comment: You didn't have to follow exactly same approach as article, it was example made for camra module. Wait i will shere a same project with you.

Comment: Check this answer, maybe this will help with what you want, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962460/how-to-reduce-the-apk-size-of-android-app-which-need-opencv-lib-only-for-image

Comment: I follow the steps from the link also but still failed. Please take a look at the EDIT 2 section I added for the error.

Comment: Can you shere full log cat output here.

Comment: Well, I am not sure but I think this issue came because apparently Gradle creates its own version of 'Android.mk' and defaults to the same API level as you have in compileSdkVersion, not minSdkVersion. `Application.mk`, so first add 'Application.mk' file with the following if you don't have one: `APP_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)  
APP_ABI := all  
APP_PLATFORM := android-19` now add this file path to your `build.gradle` file: `externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
}`

Comment: and you can check out these two posts [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096819/jni-and-gradle-in-android-studio) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740315/android-ndk-getting-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-cannot-loca?rq=1).  hope its help and if you get any error to feel free to write here again.

Comment: I finally got the solution which I already posted the answer here. Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: First congregation , and wow man!! you have done lots of work.