# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError- While loading customized .so files

Tags: android, opencv, native

OpenCV increasing size of apk So I customized OpenCV and reduced its size by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962460/how-to-reduce-the-apk-size-of-android-app-which-need-opencv-lib-only-for-image). All scripts ran fine and I got new libopencv_java4.so with reduced size. Now I updated these files into my project which already working fine (Only has issue with size) But now I am getting error like:`

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "C:/Users/ubuntu/Desktop/Development/Android/MyProject/opencv/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java4.so" needed by "libnative-lib.so"; caused by library "C:/Users/ubuntu/Desktop/Development/Android/MyProject/opencv/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java4.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
at com.abc.android.count_ai.BaseActivity.<clinit>(BaseActivity.java:11)
        at com.abc.android.sdk.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:46)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2640)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

`
I just updated newly generated customized opencv shared libs in project. Before that project was working. Am I missing something? or I have to do something with newly generated opencv .so files to make these working.

As I faced this issue I again switch to original files and ran the project. Its working. Issue is with only new files. I ran `

```
arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded libopencv_tiny.so
```

`
This command at last as given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962460/how-to-reduce-the-apk-size-of-android-app-which-need-opencv-lib-only-for-image). Is this creating problem?

Comment: You are working on windows but so file is a Unix lib. This is the root cause of what you are facing

Comment: Why are you looking for a Windows filesystem file in your Android code?  That will never work.  Your loadLibrary call needs to reference the Android filesystem location.  Not where you have it stored on your PC.  You need to add that .so file to your android app's lib files, and reference it from there by name.

Comment: @balderman I have installed ubuntu as virtual machine. Yes you are right, I am working on Windows but this error only comes when I try to use my customized file generated on ubuntu. Should this not be problem with original .so file?

Comment: @GabeSechan If this is a problem with filesystem then why it is coming only after I update libopencv_java4.so file with my customized libopencv_java4.so files. If I ran project on my same windows machine with original files, It is working. Thanks for your help Please suggest me something.